# Angular 2 and Laravel 5 Server Side Rendering

Tags: api, angular, laravel-5, server-side-rendering

I am building a shopping cart app using angular 2
i was looking a way to render angular 2 server side,

This app makes `http` calls to a `laravel 5.4 api` running in a different domain(api.domain.com) in the same server running on `nginx server`

I did install nodejs on the server but couldn't figure out a way to render the `angular 2 app`

Looking forward for much needed suggestions

Thank you

Comment: You should post an exact problem or an error that you have. What do you have and expect as an end result and what have you tried so far.

Comment: @TheFallen thank you for your time, i have built an angular 2 app using laravel 5.4 api, the problem is my website(front end angular app) is not SEO friendly so to rectify that i should do server side rending of the application, i heard it is possible if the server language is node js and i haven't find any resource on if it is possible using laravel, i just want to whether server side rendering is possible with angular 2 and laravel,